# How to execute script from multiple different file locations in Go

Tags: mongodb, go, path, scripting

I'm currently using a script to load up and tear down a MongoDB test DB for every test.
I'm doing this as follows:

```
func LoadDB() {
    cmd := exec.Command("../scripts/load_db.py")
}
```

where I call this function from each test.
The problem is that some test files are further removed than others from this script:

```
+ service1
   – service1.go
   – service1_test.go
+ service2
   + sub
      – subservice2.go
      – subservice2_test.go
    – service2.go
    – service2_test.go
```

The problem is that the working directory changes from wherever I call the function to execute the script and so relative imports don't work.  I don't want to use absolute paths because this code may be on a different machine.
What would be a good solution to be able to call the same script from multiple different locations?

Answer (score 2):

How about defining environment variables on each machine that set the absolute path of the `load_db.py` script?

Then in the `LoadDB()` func you can get the environment variable using the `Getenv()` func from the `os` package.

https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv

```
func LoadDB() {
    path := os.Getenv("LOAD_DB_PATH") // /absolute/path/to/script
    cmd := exec.Command(path)
}
```